What is the correct way to generate/validate an Okta "state" parameter aka CSRF?
I am integrating OKTA authentication in my app, and saw in their docs:

Okta requires the OAuth 2.0 state parameter on all requests to the
/authorize endpoint to prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF). The
OAuth 2.0 specification requires that clients protect their redirect
URIs against CSRF by sending a value in the authorized request that
binds the request to the user-agent's authenticated state. Using the
state parameter is also a countermeasure to several other known
attacks, as outlined in OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security
Considerations.

I am a bit unclear on what the correct approach to do this is?  Everything I have read about CSRF says putting it in a cookie is "bad"... So, if a user is not logged in, and I generate a uuid as this state param and send it to OKTA, how would I validate that state param when OKTA later calls my auth callback url with that state param?
